# How to delete all Twitter follow requests?

Tags: twitter

I have a friend who received 1500 fake follow requests on Twitter. This was likely competition or someone trying to get him banned. How can he deny all follow requests?

Comment: For something like this, I suggest contacting Twitter support.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way (atleast I do not see) to deny all follow request at once. You have to do one by one as mention on [Twitter Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169376) page.

You may search some third party tool on Google.

Comment: 6000 fake followers trying to follow. What a pain!